# How to select rows with only one relation?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have three tables which store a simple onet-to-many relationship.

```
Table1  idT1  Name
          1    A
          2    B
          3    B

Table2  idT2  Value
          1     AA
          2     BB
          3     CC 
          4     DD  

Table3   idT1  idT2
           1     4              
           1     2
           2     1
           2     4
           2     3
           3     4
```

I need to return those rows in Table3 which only have one relationship between Table1 and and some rows from Table2.

Something like this:

If I look for rows that have a relation idT2 = 4,  the query should return only this row:

```
Table3   idT1  idT2
           3     4
```

I figured out this query but I think there must be something easier:

```
    ;WITH tb AS(SELECT idT1 FROM Table3 WHERE idT2 IN(4))
    SELECT t.idT1 FROM T3 t INNER JOIN tb ON t.idT1 = tb.idT1     
    GROUP BY idT1 HAVING COUNT(t.idT2) = 1
```

Any help will be appreciated, what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use aggregation and just look for the values that appear once for a given `idT2`:

```
select idT1, max(idT2) as idT2
from t3
group by idT1
having min(idT2) = 4 and max(idT2) = 4;
```

You could also do this using `not exists`:

```
select t3.*
from t3
where t3.idT2 = 4 and
      not exists (select 1 from t3 tt3 where tt3.idT1 = t3.idT1 and tt3.idT2 <> 4);
```